# How to call the declare type methods avoiding dynamic binding?

Tags: dynamic-binding

```
Person[] p = new Person[5];
p[0] = new Student();
p[1] = new Student();
...
Arrays.sort(p);
```

Here Person is the parent class and Student is the child class. There is an overridden compareTo() method both in Person class and Student class. I want to sort Person array based on the method in Person class not in Student class. But JAVA's dynamic binding calling the method in Student class as Student is the actual type. How to solve it?